# Add Profit & Loss value inside fullCalendar in React

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, trading

I have data like this:

```js
const data = [
    {
      start: "2023-03-02",
      pl: 2,
    },
    {
      start: "2023-03-02",
      pl: -3
    },
    {
      start: "2023-03-07",
      pl: 1
    }
  ]
```

And I want to include it inside a fullCalendar like in this image [image]

If the date is the same, I want the profit/lose (pl) of the day to be added together, and color the background in red if it is negative.
How can I do this?

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/day-cell-render-hooks (probably the dayCellDidMount callback specificaly) might be your friend here - for each day it mounts, you can check your data source and find an entry for the matching day, and then update the colour and text of the cell accordingly. Have you tried anything so far? I'd also suggest trying a feed of Background Events, but I'm pretty sure it won't show the description, you'd only be able to alter the cell colour. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/background-events

Comment: I'm new to this library so I'm a little bit lost. I tried to add sample data to eventContent but It seems not working. Is there some exemple using codesanbox out there?

Comment: well you're not creating events, you're trying to populate day cells. Re-read my suggestion above and give it a try

Comment: Okay thanks I will read some docs